# elem.offsetParent in js

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at this piece of javasript from Pro JS techniques book.

He's trying to find the offsetLeft of an element. But in firefox, isn't the offsetParent always the root element body?

I'm not sure how it would recurse up.

```
// Find the X (Horizontal, Left) position of an element
function pageX(elem) {
// See if we' re at the root element, or not
return elem. offsetParent ?
// If we can still go up, add the current offset and recurse upwards
elem. offsetLeft + pageX( elem. offsetParent ) :
// Otherwise, just get the current offset
elem. offsetLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [offset parent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-cssom-view-20080222/#offset-attributes) of an element is its nearest *positioned* ancestor. My guess is that in your experiments, none of the ancestors is positioned. An element is "positioned" if it has a [`position` style property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position) (`relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`, ... I think that's all of them) that isn't `static` (which is the default), either in its `style` attribute or via a CSS selector.

So for instance, here there are no positioned elements:

```
<body>
  <p>Hi there,
      <span>I'm some text in a span inside a paragraph</span>
  </p>
</body>
```

...and so the `offsetParent` of both the paragraph and the span is the document element.

Here, we've made the paragraph *positioned*:

```
<body>
  <p style='position: relative'>Hi there,
    <span>I'm some text in a span inside a paragraph</span>
  </p>
</body>
```

...and so the `span`'s `offsetParent` is the paragraph.